# I am confused about this bash script line

Tags: bash

I am trying to convert a bash script to python for an intern project; basically, the script parses a table, and prints the information as an HTML document.

This line is confusing me. TMP is a temporary document that is the output of `lsload`, which outputs a table containing server host info.

```
# Force header text to lowercase
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <${TMP} |head --lines=+1 |sed -e 's/[ \t]\+/ /g' >${H_TMP}
```

Okay, well the first `tr` command is converting the header text from uppercase to lowercase. I'm not really sure what the `head` command is doing. And I am confused as to what the `sed` is doing as well. Could anyone clarify what is going on in this line?

As a bonus, does anyone have ideas as to how I can convert this to Python?

**EDIT**: Okay, I seem to understand what `sed` is doing; it is converting any amount of spaces or tabs to just a single space. Just confused about `head` now.

Comment: `-n, --lines=[-]K
print the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file`

Comment: I guess it would be better do do `head` command before `tr`

Comment: Perhaps your esteemed script author didn't know you can pass the output of `lsload` to `tr` without saving it to a file in between?

Comment: @CorentinLimier `tr` will only read enough of its input to fill the pipe buffer until `head` reads from the buffer. Swapping them might save some memory, depending on how much `head` reads initially.

Comment: Please have a look at [https://explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=tr+%27%5B%3Aupper%3A%5D%27+%27%5B%3Alower%3A%5D%27+%3C%24%7BTMP%7D+%7Chead+--lines%3D%2B1+%7Csed+-e+%27s%2F%5B+%5Ct%5D%5C%2B%2F+%2Fg%27+%3E%24%7BH_TMP%7D)

Comment: Wonderful resource, @kvantour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the documentation for any Unix command easily by searching for its man page.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html

Any basic introduction to the Unix command line will also reveal that `head` reads the first *n* lines of a text file, and `tail` correspondingly reads the last *n* lines of a text file.

The entire snippet corresponds to

```py
with open(os.environ['TMP']) as inputfile, open(os.environ['H_TMP'], 'w') as outputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        # sed 's/[ \t]+/ /g' is re.sub(...)
        # tr ... is lower()
        line = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ' , line).lower()
        outputfile.write(line)
        # head --lines=1 -- quit after a single line
        break
```

The regex escape `\s` matches many different whitespace characters; if your input is simply ASCII, it will overlap with the simple character class `[ \t]`. We can only guess whether you require this to match strictly those two characters if indeed you want to handle Unicode.

For maximum compactness, you could reduce this down to

```py
with open(os.environ['TMP']) as inputfile, open(os.environ['H_TMP'], 'w') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ' , inputfile.readline()).lower())
```

If you want to read a fixed number of lines where that number is not 1, maybe look at `enumerate()`:

```py
with open(os.environ['TMP']) as inputfile, open(os.environ['H_TMP'], 'w') as outputfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(inputfile, 1):
        line = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ' , line).lower()
        outputfile.write(line)
        if lineno == 234:
            break
```

Comment: To actually use this in Python, though, the loop is unnecessary. Just use `line = next(inputfile)` or `line = inputfile.readline()`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking showing it as a loop makes it easier if future visitors want to read a number of lines where the number is not 1.